# Prevent escaping characters in an xml string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to retain double quote during xml writing, I know there is lot of threads but did not get direct answer. double quote is one of example but looking some info for all xml escape character. In brief, do not want to change my raw string during writing xml.

**The reason is, do not want to modify raw string**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

data = ET.Element("data")
m_data = ET.SubElement(data, "testdata")
ET.SubElement(m_data, "user").text = '"dummy"'
xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(data)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
print (xmlstr)
```

> Ouput

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
   <testdata>
      <user>&quot;dummy&quot;</user>
   </testdata>
</data>
```

> Expected Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<data>
   <testdata>
      <user>"dummy"</user>
   </testdata>
</data>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to `\"`, but I don't think it will work since this is a special character.

Among the special characters which have to be escaped there are the following characters:

- double quote (") is escaped to `&quot;`
- ampersand (&) is escaped to `&amp;`
- single quote (') is escaped to `&apos;`
- less than (<) is escaped to `&lt;`
- greater than (>) is escaped to `&gt;`

For reading the content back, you can unescape with:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
read_content = unescape(read_content)
```

Comment: yes, do not want to modify raw string.

Comment: You don't have to. The XML writer takes care of the transformation in the background. When reading the file back, the XML reader will take care of the inverse transformation.

Comment: thanks for your input, during writing, I do not want to modify data.

Comment: The use of `unescape` might be your way to go..